# How to resolve Python error while generating Pie chart : ValueError: 'explode' must be of length 'x'

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

Can anyone help me to resolve below error while generating Pie chart with Explode option.
ValueError: 'explode' must be of length 'x'

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt

figureObject, axesObject = plt.subplots()
labels = "ABC", "XYZ"
delay = [delay1, delay2]
colors  = ("red", "green", "orange", "cyan", "brown", 
"grey","blue","indigo", "beige", "yellow")
explode = (0, 0.1, 0, 0)

# Draw the pie chart
axesObject.pie(delay,
    explode=explode,
    labels=labels,
    colors=colors,
    shadow=True,
    autopct='%1.2f',
    startangle=90,
    wedgeprops = { 'linewidth' : 2, 'edgecolor' : "cyan" })

  plt.legend(patches, labels, loc="best") 

 # Aspect ratio - equal means pie is a circle
  axesObject.axis('equal')
  plt.show()
```

additional information: I am using anaconda 3.6 version. 
I am able to generate pie chart without explode, but when I use explode I am getting  an error - ValueError: 'explode' must be of length 'x'.

Please help me, how to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mostly it helps to read [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pie.html), which says

> `matplotlib.pyplot.pie(x, explode=None ,...)`
>
> `x` : array-like
>     The input array used to make the pie chart.
>
> `explode`: array-like, optional, default: None
>   If not None, is a `len(x)` array which specifies the fraction of the radius with which to offset each wedge.

Hence if the input `x` has two elements, `explode` must also have two elements,
... and not 4 as in the code from the question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your support. Now I understand the mistake. Now my pie chart is working fine as expected. really nice. :-)